# Unhandled error Error: Data cannot be encoded in JSON error at firebase serverless functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy an api for my application. Using these codes raises Unhandled error "Error: Data cannot be encoded in JSON.

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const axios = require("axios");
exports.getDatas = functions.https.onCall(async (d)=>{
  functions.logger.log(d["name"]);
  cname = d["name"];
  ts1=d["ts1"];
  ts2=d["ts2"];
  const data =  await axios.get(
    "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/" +
    cname +
      "/market_chart/range?vs_currency=usd&from=" +
      ts1 +
      "&to=" +
      ts2,
  );
  functions.logger.log(data);
  return {data: data};
});
```

The error log is

```
Unhandled error Error: Data cannot be encoded in JSON: function httpAdapter(config) {
  return new Promise(function dispatchHttpRequest(resolvePromise, rejectPromise) {
    var onCanceled;
    function done() {
      if (config.cancelToken) {
        config.cancelToken.unsubscribe(onCanceled);
      }

      if (config.signal) {
        config.signal.removeEventListener('abort', onCanceled);
      }
    }
    var resolve = function resolve(value) {
      done();
      resolvePromise(value);
    };
    var rejected = false;
    var reject = function reject(value) {
      done();
      rejected = true;
      rejectPromise(value);
    };
    var data = config.data;
    var headers = config.headers;
    var headerNames = {};

    Object.keys(headers).forEach(function storeLowerName(name) {
      headerNames[name.toLowerCase()] = name;
    });

    // Set User-Agent (required by some servers)
    // See https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/69
    if ('user-agent' in headerNames) {
      // User-Agent is specified; handle case where no UA header is desired
      if (!headers[headerNames['user-agent']]) {
        delete headers[headerNames['user-agent']];
      }
      // Otherwise, use specified value
    } else {
      // Only set header if it hasn't been set in config
      headers['User-Agent'] = 'axios/' + VERSION;
    }

    if (data && !utils.isStream(data)) {
      if (Buffer.isBuffer(data)) {
        // Nothing to do...
      } else if (utils.isArrayBuffer(data)) {
        data = Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(data));
      } else if (utils.isString(data)) {
        data = Buffer.from(data, 'utf-8');
      } else {
        return reject(createError(
          'Data after transformation must be a string, an ArrayBuffer, a Buffer, or a Stream',
          config
        ));
      }

      if (config.maxBodyLength > -1 && data.length > config.maxBodyLength) {
        return reject(createError('Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit', config));
      }

      // Add Content-Length header if data exists
      if (!headerNames['content-length']) {
        headers['Content-Length'] = data.length;
      }
    }

    // HTTP basic authentication
    var auth = undefined;
    if (config.auth) {
      var username = config.auth.username || '';
      var password = config.auth.password || '';
      auth = username + ':' + password;
    }

    // Parse url
    var fullPath = buildFullPath(config.baseURL, config.url);
    var parsed = url.parse(fullPath);
    var protocol = parsed.protocol || 'http:';

    if (!auth && parsed.auth) {
      var urlAuth = parsed.auth.split(':');
      var urlUsername = urlAuth[0] || '';
      var urlPassword = urlAuth[1] || '';
      auth = urlUsername + ':' + urlPassword;
    }

    if (auth && headerNames.authorization) {
      delete headers[headerNames.authorization];
    }

    var isHttpsRequest = isHttps.test(protocol);
    var agent = isHttpsRequest ? config.httpsAgent : config.httpAgent;

    var options = {
      path: buildURL(parsed.path, config.params, config.paramsSerializer).replace(/^\?/, ''),
      method: config.method.toUpperCase(),
      headers: headers,
      agent: agent,
      agents: { http: config.httpAgent, https: config.httpsAgent },
      auth: auth
    };

    if (config.socketPath) {
      options.socketPath = config.socketPath;
    } else {
      options.hostname = parsed.hostname;
      options.port = parsed.port;
    }

    var proxy = config.proxy;
    if (!proxy && proxy !== false) {
      var proxyEnv = protocol.slice(0, -1) + '_proxy';
      var proxyUrl = process.env[proxyEnv] || process.env[proxyEnv.toUpperCase()];
      if (proxyUrl) {
        var parsedProxyUrl = url.parse(proxyUrl);
        var noProxyEnv = process.env.no_proxy || process.env.NO_PROXY;
        var shouldProxy = true;

        if (noProxyEnv) {
          var noProxy = noProxyEnv.split(',').map(function trim(s) {
            return s.trim();
          });

          shouldProxy = !noProxy.some(function proxyMatch(proxyElement) {
            if (!proxyElement) {
              return false;
            }
            if (proxyElement === '*') {
              return true;
            }
            if (proxyElement[0] === '.' &&
                parsed.hostname.substr(parsed.hostname.length - proxyElement.length) === proxyElement) {
              return true;
            }

            return parsed.hostname === proxyElement;
          });
        }

        if (shouldProxy) {
          proxy = {
            host: parsedProxyUrl.hostname,
            port: parsedProxyUrl.port,
            protocol: parsedProxyUrl.protocol
          };

          if (parsedProxyUrl.auth) {
            var proxyUrlAuth = parsedProxyUrl.auth.split(':');
            proxy.auth = {
              username: proxyUrlAuth[0],
              password: proxyUrlAuth[1]
            };
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (proxy) {
      options.headers.host = parsed.hostname + (parsed.port ? ':' + parsed.port : '');
      setProxy(options, proxy, protocol + '//' + parsed.hostname + (parsed.port ? ':' + parsed.port : '') + options.path);
    }

    var transport;
    var isHttpsProxy = isHttpsRequest && (proxy ? isHttps.test(proxy.protocol) : true);
    if (config.transport) {
      transport = config.transport;
    } else if (config.maxRedirects === 0) {
      transport = isHttpsProxy ? https : http;
    } else {
      if (config.maxRedirects) {
        options.maxRedirects = config.maxRedirects;
      }
      transport = isHttpsProxy ? httpsFollow : httpFollow;
    }

    if (config.maxBodyLength > -1) {
      options.maxBodyLength = config.maxBodyLength;
    }

    if (config.insecureHTTPParser) {
      options.insecureHTTPParser = config.insecureHTTPParser;
    }

    // Create the request
    var req = transport.request(options, function handleResponse(res) {
      if (req.aborted) return;

      // uncompress the response body transparently if required
      var stream = res;

      // return the last request in case of redirects
      var lastRequest = res.req || req;


      // if no content, is HEAD request or decompress disabled we should not decompress
      if (res.statusCode !== 204 && lastRequest.method !== 'HEAD' && config.decompress !== false) {
        switch (res.headers['content-encoding']) {
        /*eslint default-case:0*/
        case 'gzip':
        case 'compress':
        case 'deflate':
        // add the unzipper to the body stream processing pipeline
          stream = stream.pipe(zlib.createUnzip());

          // remove the content-encoding in order to not confuse downstream operations
          delete res.headers['content-encoding'];
          break;
        }
      }

      var response = {
        status: res.statusCode,
        statusText: res.statusMessage,
        headers: res.headers,
        config: config,
        request: lastRequest
      };

      if (config.responseType === 'stream') {
        response.data = stream;
        settle(resolve, reject, response);
      } else {
        var responseBuffer = [];
        var totalResponseBytes = 0;
        stream.on('data', function handleStreamData(chunk) {
          responseBuffer.push(chunk);
          totalResponseBytes += chunk.length;

          // make sure the content length is not over the maxContentLength if specified
          if (config.maxContentLength > -1 && totalResponseBytes > config.maxContentLength) {
            // stream.destoy() emit aborted event before calling reject() on Node.js v16
            rejected = true;
            stream.destroy();
            reject(createError('maxContentLength size of ' + config.maxContentLength + ' exceeded',
              config, null, lastRequest));
          }
        });

        stream.on('aborted', function handlerStreamAborted() {
          if (rejected) {
            return;
          }
          stream.destroy();
          reject(createError('error request aborted', config, 'ERR_REQUEST_ABORTED', lastRequest));
        });

        stream.on('error', function handleStreamError(err) {
          if (req.aborted) return;
          reject(enhanceError(err, config, null, lastRequest));
        });

        stream.on('end', function handleStreamEnd() {
          try {
            var responseData = responseBuffer.length === 1 ? responseBuffer[0] : Buffer.concat(responseBuffer);
            if (config.responseType !== 'arraybuffer') {
              responseData = responseData.toString(config.responseEncoding);
              if (!config.responseEncoding || config.responseEncoding === 'utf8') {
                responseData = utils.stripBOM(responseData);
              }
            }
            response.data = responseData;
          } catch (err) {
            reject(enhanceError(err, config, err.code, response.request, response));
          }
          settle(resolve, reject, response);
        });
      }
    });

    // Handle errors
    req.on('error', function handleRequestError(err) {
      if (req.aborted && err.code !== 'ERR_FR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS') return;
      reject(enhanceError(err, config, null, req));
    });

    // set tcp keep alive to prevent drop connection by peer
    req.on('socket', function handleRequestSocket(socket) {
      // default interval of sending ack packet is 1 minute
      socket.setKeepAlive(true, 1000 * 60);
    });

    // Handle request timeout
    if (config.timeout) {
      // This is forcing a int timeout to avoid problems if the `req` interface doesn't handle other types.
      var timeout = parseInt(config.timeout, 10);

      if (isNaN(timeout)) {
        reject(createError(
          'error trying to parse `config.timeout` to int',
          config,
          'ERR_PARSE_TIMEOUT',
          req
        ));

        return;
      }

      // Sometime, the response will be very slow, and does not respond, the connect event will be block by event loop system.
      // And timer callback will be fired, and abort() will be invoked before connection, then get "socket hang up" and code ECONNRESET.
      // At this time, if we have a large number of request, nodejs will hang up some socket on background. and the number will up and up.
      // And then these socket which be hang up will devoring CPU little by little.
      // ClientRequest.setTimeout will be fired on the specify milliseconds, and can make sure that abort() will be fired after connect.
      req.setTimeout(timeout, function handleRequestTimeout() {
        req.abort();
        var transitional = config.transitional || defaults.transitional;
        reject(createError(
          'timeout of ' + timeout + 'ms exceeded',
          config,
          transitional.clarifyTimeoutError ? 'ETIMEDOUT' : 'ECONNABORTED',
          req
        ));
      });
    }

    if (config.cancelToken || config.signal) {
      // Handle cancellation
      // eslint-disable-next-line func-names
      onCanceled = function(cancel) {
        if (req.aborted) return;

        req.abort();
        reject(!cancel || (cancel && cancel.type) ? new Cancel('canceled') : cancel);
      };

      config.cancelToken && config.cancelToken.subscribe(onCanceled);
      if (config.signal) {
        config.signal.aborted ? onCanceled() : config.signal.addEventListener('abort', onCanceled);
      }
    }


    // Send the request
    if (utils.isStream(data)) {
      data.on('error', function handleStreamError(err) {
        reject(enhanceError(err, config, null, req));
      }).pipe(req);
    } else {
      req.end(data);
    }
  });
}
    at encode (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:162:11)
    at encode (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:156:22)
    at encode (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:156:22)
    at encode (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:156:22)
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:334:22
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

First logger logs the parameter i gave correctly and the logger that logs data is in this format:

```js
...["api.coingecko.com:443::::::::::::::::::"]},"keepAliveMsecs":1000,"maxFreeSockets":256,"scheduling":"fifo","keepAlive":false,"maxSockets":null},"_removedConnection":false,"writable":true},"status":200,"data":{"prices":[[1615345414698,37.27069164629981],[1615349310788,36.95627388647297],[1615352802175,37.48630338203377],[1615356202751,37.46442850999597],[1615360079361,37.642735963063906],[1615363905145,38.29435586902702],[1615367492353,38.313292928237594],[1615370461299,38.75503558097479],[1615374138056,38.24406575020552],[1615377815960,38.237026584388175],[1615381321332,38.93964664468625],[1615384813000,39.262646397955635],[1615388739874,39.15882057568881],[1615392094129,38.94488140309047],[1615395966875,38.79820936257378],[1615399312625,38.51637055616189],[1615403055037,38.59237008394828],[1615406529740,38.44087305010874],[1615410281814,37.71855645797291],[1615414278815,38.374824600586976],[1615417716420,38.4538669693684],[1615421045728,37.62772478442999],[1615425672990,36.8826465121472],[1615429587089,37.41958697414903],[1615432278494,37.34865694722488],[1615435254265,37.16289143388951],[1615439122292,37.14731463575248],[1615442523394,36.801517989796814],[1615446290102,37.02248224990424],[1615450361470,36.164787531097126],[1615453299572,36.46191265162147],[1615457172317,36.174755169666334],[1615460886498,37.05778010952229],[1615464298322,37.336909500902365],[1615469586325,37.56497212211488],[1615472126260,37.83046394206218],[1615474882979,37.252561357731096],[1615478498201,36.56190097084664],[1615482336185,36.83824760787625],[1615485957910,36.89351702770813],[1615489642151,37.589229946501746],[1615493390438,37.33184737771527],[1615496666244,37.29234576242379],[1615500577712,37.284260441548426],[1616866645601,1137195941.0307472],[1616870299925,1089416195.9864128],[1616873841648,1074341877.495249],[1616877368137,1061555457.3375872],[1616880970910,1077775411.1216433],[1616884693948,1064594490.6022671],[1616887998472,1087481667.611567],[1616891397951,1068140794.5197278],[1616894759953,1078753362.1719048],[1616898371565,1053546315.1245787],[1616902002474,1052498816.7223371],[1616905584364,1026915395.5541993],[1616909101481,1022271206.3215427],[1616912730390,997185793.1210617],[1616916434482,972130048.6316774],[1616919928611,988711196.2721183],[1616923534317,987299160.6191593],[1616926264719,975360472.6011684],[1616930074136,958327264.7346151],[1616933292776,935085970.8922312],[1616936940791,896217168.3654604],[1616940936847,878876312.6707534],[1616944090304,890504985.5476977],[1616948321869,896715385.5657766],[1616952007508,870767231.0865391],[1616955544207,880601758.4610194],[1616958381375,896794852.1077055],[1616962022167,929362788.5783823],[1616966479654,927502494.4691795],[1616969648773,880385481.5284289],[1616973545649,862329007.9935848],[1616977463095,840138544.6360805],[1616980359587,849727926.595521],[1616984356096,820616225.3306137],[1616987602367,898085663.0760688],[1616990444958,890215727.4112909],[1616995470635,914823340.6343507],[1616999032159,890922230.685704],[1617002651977,937214914.0703756],[1617005329558,976030203.3879734],[1617009370471,1061898884.4388478],[1617012348377,1111994349.2592206],[1617015705482,1175310227.1595278],[1617019895549,1217044915.3900926],[1617022941451,1204239369.9336267],[1617027118715,1225123359.1178432],[1617031210170,1191418570.9198012],[1617033728601,1257085051.9742537],[1617037882992,1261291734.3667347],[1617041858553,1265805909.4506621],[1617044547418,1261869965.5784621],[1617049418534,1225924891.220988],[1617052450394,1200646247.466799],[1617055896172,1209247034.0807025],[1617059684123,1249662106.3996315],[1617062561979,837849935.5380555],[1617066155823,1261094295.2039979],[1617070572708,1244044711.3556864],[1617074210159,1178503497.252399],[1617077106612,1184744920.254339],[1617080571662,1219164970.9205332],[1617084836477,1174744890.1399443],[1617087739776,1236332180.5454476],[1617092763739,1121685108.4046226],[1617096303391,1074005978.1362224],[1617100013739,1075898891.906641],[1617102136947,1041120230.0169744],[1617106411165,1021062028.7444541],[1617110588848,1004207600.6385714],[1617114148509,983098685.435342],[1617117449987,983878432.6976557],[1617120868725,943893192.0239582],[1617123806180,948379973.8680001],[1617128347360,948328240.0510467],[1617131244094,923477307.6495335],[1617134866719,918321070.6284192],[1617138697011,960178009.2986945],[1617142067857,974105207.7725881],[1617146083923,973959760.0729104],[1617149999086,959500047.5209063],[1617153094367,1007753562.6156206],[1617156698445,1021534121.1115336],[1617160175611,1028067427.0339341],[1617163928330,1007755251.8882328],[1617166924538,1023240773.0466446],[1617171886674,1037535813.1806505],[1617175133694,1101375379.7094195],[1617178435173,1136688478.90344],[1617182857658,1208366620.2561867],[1617185353773,1208823054.3509212],[1617188828477,1234197192.568771],[1617193393471,1707076315.380663],[1617196301983,1845668637.7358408],[1617199516026,1901877634.1385415],[1617203681947,2015292037.1305778],[1617207515426,2141098631.115179],[1617210224998,2343473154.2871637],[1617214323265,2329074198.4966955],[1617217968405,2461828129.1798186],[1617221653017,2493042958.539376],[1617224582971,2532015555.7692595],[1617228589364,2508661361.110037],[1617232204720,2590057969.924583],[1617235260464,2749780924.550207],[1617239367664,2791689438.967896],[1617243152558,2778422749.5901804],[1617246573894,2802892972.2612605],[1617250114952,2795446026.902383],[1617253276300,2837092221.188881],[1617257741390,2957061611.281718],[1617261111556,3025594776.954216],[1617264301698,3140730366.12618],[1617267704421,3230797741.627739],[1617272276500,3247001347.7404704],[1617275862720,3182990384.8873067],[1617279129292,2889317168.9977646],[1617283053665,2753527702.506779],[1617287046529,2700392654.8781624],[1617290204012,2616296684.424929],[1617293298853,2494255828.9768047],[1617296557242,2383424694.8900166],[1617301325511,2288268623.177356],[1617303766777,2297155897.636895],[1617307669347,2314935325.319679],[1617311721980,2259716784.056617],[1617314946823,2267889595.9127536],[1617319572007,2174169254.528509],[1617323182318,2097690604.8152165],[1617326033792,2110975746.1916978],[1617329489226,2126100629.800452],[1617332409284,2193182655.044224],[1617337211709,2199847063.5248647],[1617340611316,2167549077.601362],[1617344146863,2110348803.8388174],[1617347361962,2023115590.5637138],[1617351380142,1864316761.5098753],[1617354151186,1788973202.0040677],[1617359277447,1731207666.0376515],[1617361312976,1418566500.3106787],[1617366169158,1693859181.5518322],[1617369860769,1656689094.290342],[1617372306072,1660176536.7450612],[1617376754676,1722154482.4234965],[1617379285817,1915067128.493045],[1617383311995,1982773491.2907202],[1617387963188,1985155493.939231],[1617391564495,1827213471.6221747],[1617395202777,1932891922.7380657],[1617398214973,1937931474.560893],[1617401809690,1961473630.4188676],[1617405699909,1952347409.661483],[1617409553080,2172811188.054834],[1617412963837,2431917537.219363],[1617416445822,2666886575.1140027],[1617420431122,2769520722.4907126],[1617422613890,2797409323.779513],[1617427393260,2895546310.6951184],[1617431058021,2894169435.883223],[1617433696700,2651591430.614699],[1617437513773,3448548871.8910036],[1617441138039,3537764498.5278754],[1617444820385,3662623380.0181885],[1617448128419,3729999481.3895626],[1617452094944,3741683833.307362],[1617457034540,3761774670.321721],[1617460631688,3809173022.555833],[1617464335978,3711591162.8519845],[1617467879738,3759143118.4621553],[1617471447610,3693936894.7524076],[1617474960418,3833857114.2069917],[1617478639837,3888109113.59996],[1617482233320,3857034438.9984646],[1617485821346,3898924734.2645984],[1617489477282,3952661186.2182713],[1617493109729,4002501827.9437523],[1617495709286,3872814933.0218143],[1617499443431,3939579930.8108554],[1617503699037,3663106636.5813146],[1617507443725,3808705623.491391],[1617510706891,3786240536.055139],[1617512446242,3717882675.3539762],[1617516040645,3722966733.2957063],[1617519813304,3482249884.952562],[1617523351916,3345586253.508183],[1617526909722,3327000473.8244348],[1617530664916,3181835266.2617188],[1617534176048,3094776290.1306324],[1617537924632,3064167829.684326],[1617541493704,3112790145.252149],[1617545018360,2989449570.670528],[1617548594506,3016965749.017692],[1617552471191,2973530338.557288],[1617555933696,2759208177.1915674],[1617559387440,2662906186.1813793],[1617563034515,2521716547.9565806],[1617566483711,2454800946.788864],[1617570325792,2412175803.4922743],[1617573668989,2381142461.766321],[1617577282876,2228904400.2017546],[1617580896737,2203439508.717633],[1617584514686,2083961834.3200803],[1617588367701,1922511436.832222],[1617591869391,1816453643.1859522],[1617595346098,1783362433.1356776],[1617599069131,1767878927.408502],[1617602711113,1782121869.0062866],[1617606278078,1784322317.8294444],[1617609891135,1785304724.1970084],[1617613319383,1792007217.4012969],[1617617302304,1808002080.6732872],[1617620901014,1821923720.87615],[1617624265084,1769426364.6123836],[1617629555312,1731155926.337212],[1617631504259,1735378701.9021676],[1617635133537,1942437073.2385755],[1617638780500,1938122743.6976163],[1617642119732,1932182393.8447528],[1617645707597,1918416705.3436842],[1617649325384,1925855235.7182896],[1617653252063,1944708214.0244768],[1617656889033,1932665022.73478],[1617660329160,1943687775.1192245],[1617663683699,1971924479.2343264],[1617667435208,2101421530.2666874],[1617672769205,2175322213.812557],[1617674524812,2168578229.7784457],[1617678186353,2149217571.1759067],[1617681915267,2132725563.885806],[1617685469475,1907950838.2268875],[1617689189705,2026223167.4473426],[1617692670953,1991840998.8517568],[1617696101989,1958389716.0448081],[1617699877898,2027665770.2623076],[1617703590445,2045913908.1590445],[1617707076556,2057724347.183567],[1617710622851,1722203248.9530182],[1617714225215,2160140597.446546],[1617717905528,2192080372.5552874],[1617721488585,2199844279.449877],[1617724918808,2244159138.5689125],[1617728548093,2263548854.897557],[1617732187891,2106855536.9938018],[1617735969816,2268365061.664965],[1617739538518,1863113060.588111],[1617742875565,2296819840.9881096],[1617746516853,2308037223.56185],[1617750327052,2297405821.9954567],[1617754017835,2215648462.217197],[1617758617023,2112353884.9607923],[1617761085616,2094123582.0260437],[1617764518134,2101292245.7045105],[1617768287923,2104106865.0792534],[1617771810289,2127056476.4717],[1617775566730,2152196953.3590703],[1617778865860,2160666464.579131],[1617782881414,2201171213.1865735],[1617786249160,2203934869.139618],[1617789807394,2329117281.806726],[1617793383957,2333039138.899913],[1617796986959,2491205752.3653517],[1617800521125,2652604590.3673797],[1617804331429,2692817000.168284],[1617807822435,2121796914.212729],[1617811418506,2538097921.330415],[1617815037057,2572049083.87979],[1617818698211,2550478468.4248347],[1617822347031,2541491737.3311806],[1617825969097,2609118564.630648],[1617829326876,2651351577.1099257],[1617833305171,2429954572.560337],[1617837011298,2435043578.3313527],[1617840572965,2394428204.082167],[1617843841041,2446826032.07983],[1617848315742,2395082349.188743],[1617850339793,2376349751.741466],[1617852591890,2385498650.2366877],[1617855126472,2380054416.699361],[1617858732962,2424505564.216302],[1617862619633,2434391633.272485],[1617865876330,2410962812.9744062],[1617869233838,2516114320.406959],[1617872539799,2437748581.3302546],[1617876293610,2247205079.171164],[1617880005259,2149347865.150653],[1617883394235,1893777066.5168178],[1617886836203,1757412804.559377],[1617892197847,1668727963.8671286],[1617894162445,1631584545.4824028],[1617897737215,1596293896.725426],[1617901282046,1525523967.3370435],[1617905003853,1370316987.26801],[1617908631874,1358993841.079183],[1617912335250,1404691449.9164236],[1617915995319,1379405950.1047523],[1617919567600,1366246502.7408085],[1617923270275,1289254721.1461022],[1617926622919,1386402238.6371279],[1617930228859,1384851642.1789908],[1617933705891,1365548610.2907162],[1617937372258,1357266138.9978309],[1617941122560,1335764096.6047564],[1617944870896,1322495289.1105938],[1617948462328,1283751933.8339043],[1617951863802,1272489837.990008],[1617955666499,1259096045.8789752],[1617958890026,1247182948.0102005],[1617962609987,1220448763.9536679],[1617966256703,1222538618.147044],[1617969964555,1148194206.4734476],[1617973333279,1199996169.7479842],[1617977646106,1154935691.529977],[1617980504476,1144564005.003322],[1617984273306,1132822242.6037295],[1617987925282,1136733019.0246003],[1617991396077,1139090847.1565342],[1617994822351,1133169530.4839995],[1617998615234,1113274570.5832539],[1618002141094,1094805189.6349592],[1618005876460,1035579604.067034],[1618009282025,1090335224.3969038],[1618013035782,1063984405.5106469],[1618016519119,1058097513.8615906],[1618020114108,1065381128.0365001]]}}
```

When this code invoked it logs data correctly but i can not return it at last. Anyone can help?

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the correct logging?  I'll note also that you're not building your URL safely by correctly escaping the query string parameters provided by the client.  This code is potentially open to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: As I understood I edited the question. It might give more insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you're trying to return the entire [Axios response](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema). This cannot be serialised as JSON due to circular references.

Simply return the response `data` instead. You can also make your URL construction simpler (and safer) using the `params` option

```js
exports.getDatas = functions.https.onCall(async ({ name, ts1, ts2 }) => {
  functions.logger.log(name);
  //     note the destructure here
  const { data } = await axios.get(
    `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${encodeURIComponent(name)}/market_chart/range`,
    {
      params: {
        vs_currency: "usd",
        from: ts1,
        to: ts2,
      }
    }
  );
  functions.logger.log(data);
  return { data };
});
```